# R: Calculate decile ranks by group

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, finance, rank

I have a dataframe `crsppofo` which contains monthly financial data with several variables. Of significance for my question are the following:

```
   PERMNO monthyear BetaShr
1:  85814 199501    0.5
2:  12345 199501    1.0
3:  85814 200002    1.5
4:  56789 200002    2.0
5:  12345 200002    2.5
```

`"PERMNO"` describes each individual stock, `"monthyear"` obviously shows the year and the month and `"BetaShr"` is my risk measure sorted in ascending order.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to assign decile ranks (1 to 10) according to `"BetaShr"` but grouped by `"monthyear"`. The lowest decile rank should be assigned to the lowest 10% of "`BetaShr"` of each month. The output should look like the following:

```
   PERMNO monthyear BetaShr BetaDecileRank
1:  85814 199501    0.5     1
2:  12345 199501    1.0     10
3:  85814 200002    1.5     1
4:  56789 200002    2.0     5
5:  12345 200002    2.5     10
```

Of course this is just a simplified example where only three deciles are assigned to give you an example of my desired output (assuming a range of `"BetaShr"` between 0.5 and 1.0 for 199501 and a range of 1.5 to 2.5 for 200002). You get the idea.

Through research I came up with this code:

```
library(purrr)
library(StatMeasures)
library(dplyr)
crsppofo <- crsppofo %>%
  split(crsppofo$monthyear) %>%
  map_df(~ mutate(., BetaDecileRank = decile(crsppofo$BetaShr)))
```

resulting in the error:

```
Error: Column `BetaDecileRank` must be length 2524 (the group size) or one, not 896935
```

Any help regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to improve my code or propose a completely different approach. If you need any further information let me know through the comments. I am also open for improvements regarding my question and my presence at SO as I am just a newbie in this forum as well as in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that inside the `split` group, the `decile` is applied on the whole dataset column 'BetaShr' instead of the rows from that splitted dataset

```
... %>%
    map_df(~ mutate(., BetaDecileRank = decile(crsppofo$BetaShr)))
                                               ^^^^
```

It should be

```
decile(.$BetaShr)
```

-fullcode

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(StatMeasures)
crsppofo <- crsppofo %>%
              split(crsppofo$monthyear) %>%
              map_df(~ mutate(., BetaDecileRank = decile(.$BetaShr)))
crsppofo
#  PERMNO monthyear BetaShr BetaDecileRank
#1  85814    199501     0.5              1
#2  12345    199501     1.0             10
#3  85814    200002     1.5              1
#4  56789    200002     2.0              5
#5  12345    200002     2.5             10
```

---

Note that we don't need to `split` and then loop using `map`.  Instead, it can be done by a `group_by/mutate` option

```
crsppofo %>% 
   group_by(monthyear) %>% 
   mutate(BetaDecileRank = decile(BetaShr))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   monthyear [2]
#  PERMNO monthyear BetaShr BetaDecileRank
#   <int>     <int>   <dbl>          <int>
#1  85814    199501     0.5              1
#2  12345    199501     1               10
#3  85814    200002     1.5              1
#4  56789    200002     2                5
#5  12345    200002     2.5             10
```

#### data

```
crsppofo <- structure(list(PERMNO = c(85814L, 12345L, 85814L, 56789L, 12345L
), monthyear = c(199501L, 199501L, 200002L, 200002L, 200002L), 
    BetaShr = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:"))
```